# Highlight text in webview and save it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have a webview that I display some html texts (I have them in assets). I'd like to allow users to highlight some parts of it.

I was thinking in some solutions:

1. try to put the texts user hightlight in a shared pref and use:

   webview.findAllAsync(shared_pref_string);

   webview.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

   ```
        @Override
        public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int numberOfMatches, boolean isDoneCounting) {
            // try to select the texts.
        }
    });
   ```

The problem I see is, user can select one word, like "what", and this code will select all "whats" the text has.

2. Use javascript:

   public static String Highlightscript = " <script language="javascript">" +

   ```
    "function highlightSelection(){" +
    "var userSelection = window.getSelection();" + 
    "for(var i = 0; i < userSelection.rangeCount; i++)"
    + "  highlightRange(userSelection.getRangeAt(i));" +
     "}" +
    "function highlightRange(range){"+
    "span = document.createElement(\"span\");"+
    "span.appendChild(range.extractContents());"+
    "span.setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:block;background:#ffc570;\");"+
    "range.insertNode(span);}"+
    "</script> ";
   ```

   webView.loadUrl("javascript:highlightSelection()");

But this 2 solutions not seems nice to me, any other best way to do this and more modern?

Answer (score 1):

this android library is implemented what you need:

https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android

they are using this javascript library https://github.com/timdown/rangy, maybe this will make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try this library!